# How to create ATA (Associated Token Account ) for a PDA (Program Derived Addresses) on devnet?

Tags: spl-token, pda, transfer, ata

I am creating a token-sale program, to sale tokens, I want to transfer spl-tokens to a PDA-address, so I can transfer them from PDA-token-account to recipient(transaction-signer)-token-account by signing `token::transfer` transaction using the seeds of PDA inside program

I was able to transfer spl-tokens to PDA on localnet like this:

```
sellerTknAcc = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  deployer,
  mint,
  _tokensForSalePDA,
  true // allowOwnerOfCurve - allow pda accounts to be have associated token account
);

await transferSpl(
  connection,
  deployer,
  mint,
  _tokensForSalePDA,
  exchangeBal1
);
```

But when I executed `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount()` on devnet, I got this error:
`Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests`

Then, I tried this code

```
const token_acc = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
  beybladeMint,
  tokensForSalePDA,
  true
);
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
    provider.publicKey,
    token_acc,
    tokensForSalePDA,
    beybladeMint,
    program.programId
  )
);
const txn = await provider.sendAndConfirm(transaction);
```

and got this error:

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/home/mahesh/Desktop/solana/token-sale_program/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5054:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/home/mahesh/Desktop/solana/token-sale_program/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5013:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/home/mahesh/Desktop/solana/token-sale_program/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:288:21)
    at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/home/mahesh/Desktop/solana/token-sale_program/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:148:14) {
  logs: [
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Create',
    'Program log: Error: Associated address does not match seed derivation',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 5058 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with official-rpc-provided by solana, when I used rpc from [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/), I was able to transfer spl-token to PDA-account.

Comment: Can you help to explain?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the public mainnet RPCs, such as `https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com`, you are limited in what you can do with programs to a set program list

Namely:

```
Stake11111111111111111111111111111111111111
Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111
BPFLoader1111111111111111111111111111111111
BPFLoader2111111111111111111111111111111111
BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111111111
Config1111111111111111111111111111111111111
namesLPneVptA9Z5rqUDD9tMTWEJwofgaYwp8cawRkX
```

If you try to use `getProgramAccounts` outside of those programs you won't get a successful message.

Recommendation is to use one of the many other free RPCs that are available.